# How to connect output of the optocoupler with two different circuits with different voltage levels

Tags: arduino, voltage, relay, opto-isolator

I am working the two different devices which has to connected and disconnected for my work. I am trying to use optocoupler for this switching purpose. The input of the optocoupler is connected to a vector interface with 12 V supply and in between I have used a resistor with 1.5k ohm . At the output I have connect the two different devices. One device needs 24V supply and other needs 12 V . My question is Can I use my optocoupler like this to the devices . But it did not work.

Can I use an arduino board to control the switching instead of Vector interface?
Where can I find the details for the connection and arduino code for the control?

Comment: is isolation required? what is the power demand on the transistor side of the optocoupler? If you don't need isolation, a simple MOSFET should do the trick, and you don't need to worry about the current transfer.